# multiple date formats in a column

Tags: python, datetime

I have two date formats in a column `2020-02-19 00:00:00` and `12-MAR-2021`. I want to bring the whole column to a homogeneous date format of `%Y-%m-%d`. How can I do this?
I have tried using `pd.to_datetime()` but its not working with multiple formats

Comment: the example `pd.to_datetime(['2020-02-19 00:00:00', '12-MAR-2021'])` is working pretty well for me - what specific error do you get, and which version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.3+ you can use timestamp() instead:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2012,4,1,0,0).timestamp()
1333234800.0
```

This is number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970 in UTC, can be used as a good common format

Comment: the OP is looking to convert string to datetime, not datetime to Unix time.